# Testing Rails Route in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes, jasmine

I have a navbar partial view:

_navbar.html.erb

```
<nav class="nav-links">
   <ul>
     <li><%= link_to "Mastermind", root_path, :id => 'logo'%></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When you click "Mastermind", it reloads the page:

```
function reloadPage() {
  location.reload();
}

function logoReload() {
  $('#logo').click(reloadPage);
}
```

How come this jasmine test will not work?

```
describe("button click", function() {
  var btn;
  beforeEach(function() {
    btn = $('#logo');
  });

 it("should reload the page", function() {
    spyOn(window, 'reloadPage');
    $(btn).click();
    expect(window.reloadPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I get the response: Error: Expected spy reloadPage to have been called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are spying on `window` but call `reload` on `location`. Change your example:

```
it("should reload the page", function() {
  spyOn(location, 'reloadPage');
  $(btn).click();
  expect(location.reloadPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```